# Ksoap2 add property(Android)

Tags: android, ksoap2

My question should be quite simple to those who always use ksoap2 library.One of my web method in web service have two attribute so may i know how to use addproperty from eclipse to pass two data to web services.Plz provide an example short code.

Comment: what do you mean by two data?

Comment: google it out .. u will find lot of examples

Comment: public void ProductImageInsertion(String name,Byte imageLink) //something like the example above....i need to input two data to the void function

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String Login(Context c, String username, String password,
            String fleetId) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/xxxxxx/";
        SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(CommonVariable.NAMESPACE,
                METHOD_NAME);
        // Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("username", username);
        request.addProperty("password", password);
        Log.i("request", "request:" + request);
        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        Log.i(WebCalls, "URL " + CommonVariable.URL);
        Log.i(WebCalls, "Method Name " + METHOD_NAME);
        Log.i(WebCalls, "request Name " + request);
        String SoapResult = null;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                CommonVariable.URL);

        // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            SoapResult = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
        } else {
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapResult = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
        }

        Log.i(WebCalls, "Response " + SoapResult);

        return SoapResult;
    }
```

you want to add property in webservice like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(CommonVariable.NAMESPACE,
                METHOD_NAME);
        // Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("username", username);
        request.addProperty("password", password);
```

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: You should write something about the code, simple code in answer is not valid answer.

Comment: For example:public void ProductImageInsertion(String name,Byte imageLink)     //i need to input two data to this void function but i only know how to add property to one function, when i try two my logcat will SoapFault